# Does a Qinggon monk fulfill the requirements to take craft magical arms and armor feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats, monk, archetype

My group has just reached level 6 and we still do not have magic weapons, largely because we are well under WBL and considerable spending on side resources such as rations.

I have been researching crafting magic arms and armor seeing if there was a way for my [Qinggon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk) Zen Archer Monk to maybe help with this, since its not downtime thats an issue.

So first I came across [master craftsman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-craftsman---final) which when you have enough ranks, allows you to take some magic item creation feats. This has considerable investment when it comes to skill points.

But it did cause me to look more closely at [craft magical arms and armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-magic-arms-and-armor-item-creation---final) where the only prerequisite is a caster level of 5.

Now, as I am a Quinggon Monk, I have chosen some ki powers which are spells, and thus become spell-like abilities. But more importantly is the following:

> Spells: These ki powers duplicate the effects of a spell, and are spell-like abilities. A qinggong monk’s class level is the **caster level** for these spell-like abilities, and she uses Wisdom to determine her concentration check bonus.

So this specifically states I have a caster level equal to my monk class level. So I went to check out what [magic rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Caster-Level) had to say about caster level. Which had little to say.

> A spell's power often depends on its caster level, which for most spellcasting characters is equal to her class level in the class she's using to cast the spell.
>
> You can cast a spell at a lower caster level than normal, but the caster level you choose must be high enough for you to cast the spell in question, and all level-dependent features must be based on the same caster level.
>
> In the event that a class feature or other special ability provides an adjustment to your caster level, that adjustment applies not only to effects based on caster level (such as range, duration, and damage dealt), but also to your caster level check to overcome your target's spell resistance and to the caster level used in dispel checks (both the dispel check and the DC of the check).

As far as I can tell, my monk fulfills the requirements to take the craft magical arms and armor feat and being crafting magical things. Yes because I do not have the required spells it will be at an increased DC, however I will be maxing out spellcraft, and hopefully having others in the group assist with the crafting. ***Am I correct about this, or have I missed something?***

Some useful information which I came across while researching this are:

- [How does the Master Craftsman feat work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21593/how-does-the-master-craftsman-feat-work)
- http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2jy0j?Master-Craftsman-Clarification

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A caster level from [spell-like abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-) is insufficient to meet a caster level prerequisite for an [item creation feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats)

The [*Pathfinder Core Rulebook* FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm) on Item Creation includes [this brief exchange](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qp0):

> **Does having a caster level from a spell-like ability meet the caster level prerequisite for selecting an item creation feat?**
>   No.

Thus a [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk) with the archetype [qinggong monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk) usually must still be able to cast real spells to have a caster level like that needed to meet the prerequisite of, for example, the feat [Craft Magic Arms and Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-magic-arms-and-armor-item-creation---final). (Similarly insufficient is, for example, the typical [aasimar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-aasimar)'s racial spell-like ability *daylight*.)

This GM would also extend this ruling to [supernatural abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-). Hence, for example, in this GM's campaign, the traditional level 11 [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk)'s supernatural ability [abundant step](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Abundant-Step-Su-)—although explicitly granting the monk a caster level—would also be insufficient to meet caster level prerequisites of item creation feats.

Comment: Took me awhile to find the specific ruling,
http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qp0

Comment: @Fering (Psst! That's the same one I linked to in the answer; click on *this brief exchange* in the answer. I wouldn't stick that in there without a link, man. I'm not a monster! `:-)`)

Comment: I clicked on the first link, not the second, good point